# Setting prototype's object's field changes all instances

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0rsasq1/4/)

```
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
Person.prototype = {
    nationality : {
        type : ""
    },
    changeNationality:function(n){
        this.nationality.type = n;
    }
};

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");

var myMother = new Person("Jane", "Doe", 50, "blue");

myMother.changeNationality("English");
myFather.changeNationality("German");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My father is " + myFather.nationality.type + "<br/> My mother is " + myMother.nationality.type;
```

When i change the nationality of myFather it changes myMother's nationality too. What can be the reason?

Comment: Obviously!! This is how prototype works in javascript. To prevent assign directly to  Person.prototype.nationality = "XYZ"

Answer (score 1):

Because you're defining `nationality` at the `prototype` level instead of the `Person` instance, thats the very reason for the `prototype`! The idea is to be shared among all the class instances, otherwise every instance would have its own definition of every method, using much more memory and potentially diverging behaviors.

Try moving `nationality` to the constructor function:

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
    this.nationality = { type: "" };
}
```

Comment: But when i make the nationality simple string then every object has its own nationality. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/d0rsasq1/7

Answer (score 1):

Since the prototype is shared along every instance of your object definition, you should do something like this:

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
    this.nationality = {
        type : ""
    };
}
Person.prototype = {
    
    changeNationality:function(n){
        this.nationality.type = n;
    }
};

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");

var myMother = new Person("Jane", "Doe", 50, "blue");

myMother.changeNationality("English");
myFather.changeNationality("German");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My father is " + myFather.nationality.type + "<br/> My mother is " + myMother.nationality.type;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: If prototype is shared along every instance then why does not it change other instances when you set just a string field of prototype. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/d0rsasq1/7/

Comment: because string var is referenced by value and object var by reference.

Answer (score 0):

> To prevent this assign properties to the prototype using **one
>   level dot and string assignments.**

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
    this.changeNationality = function(n){
        this.nationalityType = n
    }
}

Person.prototype.nationalityType = 'default';

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");

var myMother = new Person("Jane", "Doe", 50, "blue");
myMother.changeNationality("English");
myFather.changeNationality("German");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My father is " + myFather.nationalityType + "<br/> My mother is " + myMother.nationalityType;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
changeNationality:function(n){
        this.nationality.type = n;
    }
```

to

```
changeNationality:function(n){
        this.nationality = {type : n};
    }
```

should also work because setting a property will create a new one on the object. But in case of             `this.nationality.type = n;`

this.nationality is a get and doing .type on that is set hence it will assign the value from where it get it i.e from prototype. Hence you are getting the behaviour. I have updated the fiddle you can check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d0rsasq1/8/)